# mongod src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp no file

Tags: mongodb

I've really been all over StackOverflow on this and couldn't find a solution. I have uninstalled Homebrew and Mongo via, well, brew. Nothing seems to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7684 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Matts-MacBook-Pro.local
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.6
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: c55eb86ef46ee7aede3b1e2a5d184a7df4bfb5b5
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-08-03T20:29:40.017-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-08-03T20:29:40.018-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-08-03T20:29:40.019-0400 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1501806580:19955][7684:0x7fffbdc783c0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
2017-08-03T20:29:40.029-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 269
2017-08-03T20:29:40.029-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating
2017-08-03T20:29:40.029-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-08-03T20:29:40.029-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-08-03T20:29:40.029-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-08-03T20:29:40.029-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-08-03T20:29:40.029-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Comment: No such directory `/data/db`. And it's actually a commonly asked question. Actually says that in the error message `No such file or directory`

Comment: It's not saying that folder isn't present, it's saying the wired tiger file is missing. Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually the **error is saying** that **the directory is not present** which would be the most likely cause. If it actually is present and accessible by permissions and there is something in there, then something has gone horribly wrong that you are not mentioning. If in fact this is a "new install" then it would be advisable to clean all content of the directory and let the startup create "fresh" data files.

Comment: Typically correct installs do not even use `/data/db` and have an alternate location. So it's presence in the error message indicate you are simply running `mongod` on the command like with "no other options". You should perhaps go back and refer  to the install instructions, as well as look at the documentation on [`mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) as well as the [Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) as these relate to how you typically run MongoDB.

Comment: @soldfor how did you fix this issue. I am also facing same issue

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda no idea. Lol. It's a question for over two years ago. I no longer use mongodb tho.

Comment: @soldfor still do you have that error

Comment: because in my case i can found a solution

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda I may or I may not. No idea. I deleted mongo from my laptop, so I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Oh. anyway i will add what i did as an answer. it might help someone else who having this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I also have to spent more than 4 hours to find a solution you asked. In my case, the stack trace is same as in your case.

I used MongoDB 4.2. But I need to downgrade it to MongoDB 3.4. After downgrading to 3.4 above error can be seen. Then again I updated MongoDB to 4.2. Still there was that error.

Tried many solutions on Stack Overflow but nothing solved my issue. As my final option I run below command.

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

But it also did not work. 
There were some files on my `/data/db` directory.

Those are WiredTiger, WiredTiger.lock, WiredTiger.turtle, diagnostic.data, journal and mongod.lock.

Removed all the files in `/data/db` directory.

```
rm -rf /data/db/*
```

Run above command with `sudo` if you are not the root user.

Then I run `mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair` command again.

Then I could start MongoDB successfully by running `mongod --dbpath /data/db`.

Do not forget add `bin/mongod` to PATH in .bash_profile(If you are using Mac).